# Check subquery against multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'd like to check a subquery against more than one value.
Something like:

```
... WHERE (value1 OR value2) IN ([subquery])
```

The above line does not work?
Is this even possible?
How to do this?

I now use a workaround, but it does not look efficient.

```
SELECT id FROM project 
        WHERE 
        (   subcategory IN 
            (
                SELECT id
                FROM other_table WHERE value LIKE ?
            )
            OR subcategory2 IN 
            (               
                SELECT id
                FROM other_table WHERE value LIKE ?
            )
        )
```

Comment: You can use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Put value1 and value2 in the where of your subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is converting to an `exists` subquery:

```
where  exists
       (
       select  *
       from    other_table
       where   value like ?
               and id in (subcategory, subcategory2)
       )
```